# MailSendException SSLHandshakeException JavaMail emails not being sent

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, tomcat8, sslhandshakeexception, starttls

When sending an email using JavaMail, I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
```

I am using Tomcat 8 in which I have these arguments added:

```
-Dcatalina.home=C:\Development\apache-tomcat-8.5.12
-Dcatalina.base=C:\Development\apache-tomcat-8.5.12
-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Development\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Development\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\conf\logging.properties
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+UseG1GC
-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true 
-Dmail.debug=true
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

My java mail properties are:

```xml
<property name="javaMailProperties">
  <props>
      <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
      <prop key="mail.smtp.debug">true</prop>
      <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
  </props>
</property>
```

I am using Spring Java Mail v.3.2.2.

The weirdest thing is that this configuration has been properly working for years but now around suddenly 80% of the emails are not being sent due to this. However, the other 20% of the emails are sent as usual.

I have reviewed the configuration in the remote server and nothing has been changed.

Comment: nothing changed - except time passed!? (certificate expired/renewed!?;) hi & welcome to [so]!

Comment: You may want to enable SSL debugging to see if anything is shown there. Also talk to the system administrator of your SMTP server.

Comment: Second the motion for `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake` . What java version? Tomcat 8.5 can run on 7, which was the last version with PermGen, and at least the free versions of 7 (through 7u80) by default disabled TLS client protocols above 1.0, while many servers today require 1.1 or even 1.2 minimum because 1.0 is if not outright broken at least seriously weakened. Note `https.protocols` has no effect at all on mail, which does not use HTTP[S]; if you meant to configure TLS versions for SMTP use `mail.smtp.ssl.protocols`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to all those who replied.

It appears that all the problem was cause by a change on Microsoft policies regarding the basic authentication for their tenants.

After some changes on the account settings, all is back to normal and the emails are sent again.